# How to calculate an answer in a function and then print it from the main() function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program which will calculate a number based on a set of pre-set numbers. I've managed to do it, however, I need the printf part which displays the answer to be in the main() function rather than being in the function which does the calculation, and i'm not quite sure how to do it.

I've tried to just move the printf underneath main, but it says that the variables are not defined. I've also tried to put a main() after the equation calculation is done, but this doesn't work either.

The code below does what I want it to do, apart from the fact that print if is located in the equation function, rather than in the main, which is what i'm not quite sure on how to do.

My code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void equation(double Rstar, double fp, int ne, double f1, double 
    fi, double fc, int L)
    {
        int N = Rstar * fp * ne * f1 * fi * fc * L;
        printf("N=%d, Rstar=%.1f, fp=%.1f, ne=%d, f1=%.1f, fi=%.1f, fc=%.1f, L=%d",N,Rstar,fp,ne,f1,fi,fc,L);

    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        equation(1.0,0.2,1,1.0,1.0,0.1,1000);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Functions can return values.

Comment: Aside: why `int N` when the result of the multiplications is `double`?

Comment: @WeatherVane my instructions say to return N as a non-negative integer so i'm just following along

Comment: @xKetjow suppose the product is out of range of `int`? And if it is required to be non-negative would a value of `unsigned int` be better than `int`? And since you say "integer" would `unsigned long long` be even better?

Comment: ...because that is the maximum non-negative integer range you can get from `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your function return the calculated result and prin t the returned value in the `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int equation(double Rstar, double fp, int ne, double f1, double 
fi, double fc, int L)
{
    int N = Rstar * fp * ne * f1 * fi * fc * L;

    return N;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = equation(1.0,0.2,1,1.0,1.0,0.1,1000);

    printf("N=%d, Rstar=1.0, fp=0.2, ne=1, f1=1.0, fi=1.0, fc=0.1, L=1000",N);

    return 0;
}
```

I would, however, recommend on defining a `struct` which would hold all the input parameters, and then the function `equation` would get pointer to that struct instead of 7 parameters.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct equ_input_t
{
    double rStart;
    double fp;
    int ne;
    double f1;
    double fi;
    double fc;
    int L;
} equ_input_t;

int equation(const equ_input_t *input)
{
    int N = input->rStart * input->fp * input->ne * input->f1 * input->fi * input->fc * input->L;

    return N;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    equ_input_t param = {.rStart = 1.0, 
                         .fp     = 0.2, 
                         .ne     = 1, 
                         .f1     = 1.0, 
                         .fi     = 1.0, 
                         .fc     = 0.1, 
                         .L      = 1000 };

    int N = equation(&param);

    printf("N=%d, Rstar=%.1f, fp=%.1f, ne=%d, f1=%.1f, fi=%.1f, fc=%.1f, L=%d", 
            N, param.rStart, param.fp, param.ne, param.f1, param.fi, param.fc, param.L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use this but i've not looked at it in lectures yet, also, i've put the return N; bit in the equation function and then changed around the printf and it's telling me that N is an undeclared variable

Comment: @xKetjow Where do you get such error? In what line? Here it works just fine: https://ideone.com/tSkryG

Comment: https://ideone.com/1yWQ4b here, it's the first example that you posted.

EDIT: Nevermind i've forgotten to add something to the start in main()

Comment: @xKetjow Looks like you didn't copy correctly the `main()` function. Please copy & paste it again

Answer (score 1):

You should have your function *return* the result like so:

```
int equation(double Rstar, double fp, int ne, double f1, double 
fi, double fc, int L)
{
    int N = Rstar * fp * ne * f1 * fi * fc * L;
    return N;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = equation(1.0,0.2,1,1.0,1.0,0.1,1000);
    printf("N: %d\n", N);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that function return type is changed from *void* to *int*.

Comment: Is it possible to return all the variables and not just N, so return N, Rstar, fp, ne, f1, fi, fc, L; ? I've just tried it and it didn't work, but i've probably done something wrong.

Comment: it is possible to "return" multiple values.  the reason i'm using quotes is that you would to that through pointers in the function parameters.  but this is probably outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: @xKetjow why would you want to return all  the variables passed, since you already know what they are, because you passed them to the function?

Comment: @WeatherVane is correct, you don't really need to return values that you pass in, unless you plan on modifying them in the function, but currently that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I'm going to run the same equation 3 more times but with different values in each run for all the variables, but I think this should work too

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the `equation()` function to be of type `int`, and return N.  `main()` can then say `X = equation ...` and `printf()` from there.